# Proof by Strong Induction: $n = 2^a b,\, b\,$ odd, every natural a product of an odd and a power of 2

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction, divisibility

Can someone guide me in the right direction on this question?

Prove that every $n$ in $\mathbb{N}$ can be written as a product of an odd integer and a non-negative integer power of $2$.

For instance: $36 = 2^2(9)$ , $80 = 2^4(5)$ , $17 = 2^0(17)$ , $64 = 2^6(1)$ , etc...

Any hints in the right direction are appreciated (please explain for a beginner).
Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To prove something by strong induction, you have to prove that

> If all natural numbers strictly less than $N$ have the property, then $N$ has the property.

is true for all $N$.

So: our induction hypothesis is going to be:

> Every natural number $k$ that is strictly less than $n$ can be written as a product of a power of $2$ and an odd number.

And we want to prove that from this hypothesis, we can conclude that $n$ itself can be written as the product of a power of $2$ and an odd number.

Well, we have two cases: either $n$ is odd, or $n$ is even. If we can prove the result holds in both cases, we'll be done.

**Case 1:** $n$ is odd. Then we can write $n=2^0\times n$, and we are done. So in Case 1, the result holds for $n$.

**Case 2:** If $n$ is even, then we can write $n=2k$ for some natural number $k$. But then $k\lt n$, so we can apply the induction hypothesis to $k$. We conclude that `...and you should finish this part...`

So we conclude that the result holds for all natural numbers by strong induction.

Comment: So if k < n then by induction hypothesis k can be written as a product of a power of 2 and an odd number? Then that would imply that n itself follows from the hypothesis?

Comment: @1337holiday: I assume you are talking about case 2. Not "if", but **since** $k\lt n$, then $k$ can be written as a product of a power of $2$ and an odd number (by the induction hypothesis). So $k=2^r\times s$, where $s$ is odd. What does that tell you about $n$?

Comment: So since n = 2k and k = (2^r(s)). It means that n = 2(2^r(s)) or n = (2^(r+1))(s) and therefore it is true by the hypothesis?

Comment: @1337holiday: Essentially yes: though I would phrase it as "and therefore, $n$ can be written as the product of a power of $2$ and an odd number." The induction hypothesis has already been invoked, no need to remember her yet again in the coda. (-:

Comment: THIS IS AMAZING! I didnt understand this at all but now im starting to get it. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

This follows from a more general result that's both simpler to prove and *more insightful*, viz. the result follows immediately by this frequently applicable **multiplicative form of induction**, which shows that for multiplicative sets we need only check the generators (here $1$ and primes).

**Lemma** $\rm\, \mathbb N$ is the only set of naturals containing $\color{#c00}1$ and $\rm\color{#c00}{all\ primes}$ and $\rm\color{#0a0}{\text {closed under product}}$.

**Proof** $\ $ Suppose $\rm\!\ S\subset \mathbb N\,$ has said properties. $ $ We prove by strong induction every natural $\rm\!\ n\in S.\, $  If $\rm\,n\,$ is $\,\color{#c00}1\,$ or $\color{#c00}{\rm prime}$ then by hypothesis $\rm\,n\in S.\,$ Else $\rm\,n\,$ is composite, $ $ hence $\rm\ n = j k\ $ for $\rm\, j,k < n.\,$ By strong induction the smaller $\rm\ j,k\in S,\,$ $\rm\color{#0a0}{thus}$ $\rm\, n = jk\in S.\   $ $\small\bf QED$

This yields the sought result. Let $\rm\!\ S\!\ $ be the set of naturals that have the form $\rm\,2^{\,j}\!\ n\,$ for odd $\rm\,n\in \mathbb N.\ $ $\, 1\!\ $ and all primes $\rm\,p\,$ are in $\rm\!\ N,\, $ by $\, 2 = 2^{\!\ 1}\!\cdot\! 1\,$ and $\rm\, p = 2^{\!\ 0}\!\cdot\! p\,$ for odd $\rm\,p\,$ (and $1).$ $\rm\,S\!\ $ is closed under multiplication by $\rm\, (2^{\,j}\!\ m) (2^{\,k}\!\ n) = 2^{\,j+k}\!\ m\!\ n,\, $ with $\rm\!\ m\!\ n\!\ $ odd by $\rm\!\ m,n\!\ $ odd. $\!\ $ So $\rm\ S = \mathbb N\ $ by Lemma.

---

**Corollary** $\ $ Every natural $> 0\,$ is a product of primes (i.e. irreducibles).

**Proof** $\, $ It is clear for $1$ and primes, and products of primes are closed under multiplication.

**Remark** $ $ We could also deduce the sought result from the prior Corollary. Then it reduces to (inductively) proving that a product of $n$ odds remains odd. But this way is not an instructive example of strong induction, since the strong induction is hidden in the proof of the corollary.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2361850/242) for a direct proof of the Lemma specialized to this case.

Answer (score 0):

Proof:

By the fundamental theorem of algebra, every integer $N$ can be uniquely factored as $\prod^{n}_{i=1}p_{i}^{a_{i}}$. Now, mark $2=p_{1}$, note $a_{i}$ can take value of $0$. You got the theorem.

For the "inductive" proof, suppose for $n<k$ this is true. For $n+1$ its factors must be in previous $n$ numbers. Hence $n+1=\prod n_{i}$. Decompose $n_{i}$ by induction hypothesis you get the statement.

Comment: @user7887: The Fundamental Theorem of Algebra says that every nonconstant polynomial with complex coefficients has at least one complex root; you mean the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic.

Comment: now I understand.

Comment: @user7887: Your inductive proof has two problems: first, the OP asked for a proof by *strong* induction, not regular induction. Second, your argument is incorrect as given (it's possible for $n+1$ to be prime, after all).

Comment: I don't think $n+1=\prod n_i$ is true (should be $p_i$), and if $n+1$ is prime its factor(s) are not in the previous $n$ numbers.  You are close-if $n+1$ is prime, it is odd.

Comment: I guess answering more such questions can help me realize my own weakness. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: @Ross: Unless $n=1$... there's a reason why this proof is so much easier with "true for all $k\lt n\Rightarrow$ true for $n$"-induction than with "true for $n\Rightarrow$ true for $n+1$"-induction.

Comment: @Arturo: You are right about the advantage of strong induction over (weak, simple-which is your favorite?) induction.  I was focused on the case where the number in question was prime, where you can't factor it into smaller numbers.  Your comment on this subject came in while I was writing mine.

Comment: @Ross: I call it "regular induction", which is probably just as big a misnomer as calling the other one "strong". (-:

Comment: @Arturo:  works for me.