# Strong Induction: Every natural number $n\geq 8$ can be represented as $n=3k + 5\ell$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Can you please help me and tell, how should I move on? 
Can this be proved by induction?

> Every natural number $n\geq 8$ can be represented as $n=3k + 5\ell$.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please note that [linear algebra] is a particular discipline that deals with vectors, vector spaces, linear transformations, and matrices; it is an inappropriate tag for both questions you have asked so far.

Comment: Are $k$ and $l$ natural numbers?And have you tried to see if this is true for $n=9$?

Comment: @smanoos: Remember that "naturals" often include $0$.

Comment: We need to be slightly more specific. The assertion should be that every natural number $n \ge 8$ can be represented as $n=3k+5l$, where $k$ and $l$ are non-negative integers.  Check for $8$, $9$, $10$. Now is it clear?  Yes, we can use induction, but you can do it without mentioning induction explicitly.

Comment: This is one case of the Frobenius coin problem.  A discussion is at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem

Comment: Is this not [an exact duplicate?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/69961/11619)

Comment: Same: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1181222

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint** $ \,n\,$ representable $\Rightarrow$ so too is $\,n\!+\!\color{#c00}3$ (by adding $1$ to $ k)$ so if $\,\color{#c00} 3\,$ consecutive integers $\,8,9,10\,$ are representable then induction $\Rightarrow$ so too are all larger integers $\,3\!+\![8,9,10],\,$ $\, 6\!+\![8,9,10]\,\ldots$

Rigorously: $\!\bmod 3\!:\ 8,9,10\equiv 2,0,1$ [is a complete set of residues](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1866966/242) (remainders) $\!\bmod 3,\,$ so every natural $n$ is congruent to one of them, say $\,n\equiv r,\,$ so $\,n = 3q+r,\,$ and $\,n\ge 8\Rightarrow q\ge 0,\,$ so we can add three $q$ times to $r$ to get $n$, i.e. $\, r = 3k+5\ell\Rightarrow n = 3q+3k+5\ell = 3(q+k)+5\ell$.

**Remark** $ $  Above the induction is encapsulated in the Division with Remainder Algorithm (the special case $\,n\div 3,\,$ i.e. every natural $n = 3q+r$ for $\,0\le r\le 2)$. The same idea works for any number of integers (or "coins", "stamps", "McNuggets", etc). For some underlying geometric intuition see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66975/242) on this so-called Frobenius problem (which includes a list of many of its related names to aid in literature searches).

Explicitly: $\quad n\ =\ 3\bigg[\dfrac{n-5\:\ell}{3}\bigg] + 5\:\!\ell\ \ $ for $\ \ \ell\: = \ {-}n\bmod 3,\ \ \ell \in \{0,1,2\}$

yields the desired representations for all integers $\ge 8.$

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/8200/242) gives a general form of the above inductive proof.

Comment: Thank you for the response!
I'm really beginner in "real" math,that's why I have to ask you some more questions. 

Could you please explain, what does the last part mean: k∈{0,1,2},  k≡−n(mod3). I've just read about congruence relation in wikipedia, but didn't understand, why -8 and 7 are congruent mod 5 (-8/5 rest -3; 7/5 rest 2 O_o). And in your hint k and -n are congruent mod 3. 

Could you please give me some more explanation.

Comment: @Lissa I've added some examples in the answer.

Answer (score 9):

Clearly, $8$ can be represented as $3k+5\ell$, by taking $k=1$ and $\ell=1$.

Likewise, $9=3(3) + 5(0)$; and $10=3(0) + 5(2)$. So we can represent $8$, $9$, and $10$.

Now, assume that for  $m\gt 10$, and you can represent all numbers strictly smaller than $m$ that are $8$ or larger (the induction hypothesis). To show that you can represent $m$, consider $m-3$ first.

Comment: I think you mean $3(3)$ and not $3(2)$.

Comment: @smanoos: why, yes, I did! Thank you. (-:

Comment: Thank you for response! I have some questions.

By k>10 you mean some n'>10?
What do you mean "To show that you can represent k, consider k−3 first"?

IS looks like: n'+1 = 3k+5l, but I cannot move from this point.

Comment: @Lissa: What you call the number on which you are doing induction does not matter. I like to call it "$k$"; if you want to call it "$n'$", I don't think the number is likely to object. Note that I am **not** doing regular induction ("assume it's true for $k$, show it is true for $k+1$"), I am using so-called **strong** induction ("assume it is true for every number strictly smaller than $k$, show it is true for $k$").(cont)

Comment: @Lissa: (cont) See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25914/proof-by-strong-induction/25919#25919), and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/14984/what-is-the-second-principle-of-finite-induction/14987#14987). The induction hypothesis, which I stated explicitly, is that every number less than $k$ (and greater than or equal to $8$) can be represented. We need to prove that $k$ can be represented. Now, if $k\gt 10$, then $k-3$ is a number that is smaller than $k$; and greater than or equal to $8$. So our induction hypothesis says that we can represent $k+3$. Go from there?

Comment: @Arturo I think the issue here was that $k$ already has a meaning in the context of this problem.

Comment: @MartianInvader: Oh, sigh. Quite right.

Answer (score 5):

We can avoid an explicit appeal to induction by using the fact that every natural number $n$ has remainder $0$, $1$, or $2$ on division by $3$.  Let $n \ge 8$.

If $n$ has remainder $2$ on division by $3$, then $n-8$ is divisible by $3$, say $n-8=3m$. Represent $8$ using $8=3\cdot 1+5\cdot 1$. Then add $m$ $3$'s.

If $n$ has remainder $0$ on division by $3$, then $n-9$ is divisible by $3$, say $n-9=3m$. Represent $9$ using $9=3\cdot 3 +5\cdot 0$. Then add $m$ $3$'s.

If $n$ has remainder $1$ on division by $3$, then $n-10$ is divisible by $3$, say $n-10=3m$. Represent $10$ using $10=3\cdot 0 +5\cdot 2$. Then add $m$ $3$'s.

The argument for remainder $0$ was a little silly, since if $n$ has remainder $0$ on division by $3$, we can clearly use a bunch of $3$'s to represent $n$. But we wanted the solutions for the three cases to use a single template.

Comment: More explicitly, see my answer, which unifies the cases.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque: We have opposite tendencies. I use $100$ words when $50$ will do.

Comment: @André Nicolas, thank you for detailed answer - exactly the way, I need :) 
Please, can you tell, what are we doing here in general words? The principle?

Comment: We are finding non-negative solutions of linear diophantine equations. In general, if $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime positive integers, for any $n > ab-a-b$ there are non-negative integers $x$, $y$ such that $ax+by=n$.