# Idea of the Proof : Existence of a & b so that (Any integer greater than 8) = 3a + 5b

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Claim:** Prove that for every integer $n \geq 8$, there exist nonnegative integers $a$ and $b$ such that $n = 3a + 5b.$
>
> **Proclaimed solution :** Let $n ∈ \mathbb{Z}$ with $n ≥ 8.$ $\text{ Then } n = 3q, \text{ where } q ≥ 3, \quad \text{ or } n = 3q+1, \text{ where } q ≥ 3, \quad \text{ or } n = 3q+2, \text{ where } q ≥ 2.$
>   We consider these three cases. (Rest of proof omitted)

I do not apprehend the above parts of the proof BEFORE (Rest of proof omitted). However, I understand and completed the rest of the proof that I omitted. I recognise that it uses the result that division of any integer by $n$ must yield a remainder of $0, 1, 2, ..., n - 2, 
\text{ or } n - 1$.

$1.$ However, what is the idea or strategy of the proof?

$2.$ What motivates or propounds the claim?

$3.$ Is there a more natural or easier proof?

I referenced [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72630/every-natural-number-n-geq-8-can-be-represented-as-n-3k-5-ell?lq=1). Source: P102, Problem 4.9 on P101 (related to P90, Result 4.8) of *Mathematical Proofs, 2nd ed* by Chartrand et al.

Comment: http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_Lemma

Comment: Essentially it means if you can establish the result for $n = 8, 9, 10$, any larger number can be obtained by adding positive multiples of $3$ to one of these.

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/70040/11619) by Robjohn. Close to being a duplicate.
Also, look at the wikipedia article on [numerical semigroups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_semigroup).

Answer (score 3):

More generally, given coprime positive integers $n, m$, every integer $z$ greater than or equal to $(n-1)(m-1)$ can be written in the form
$$
z = a n + b m
$$
for non-negative integers $a, b$.

---

Here's a proof

First find integers $x_0, y_0$ such 
$z = x_0 n - y_0 m.$
Now we know that the solutions $x, y$ of
$$
z = x n + y m
$$
are of the form
$$
x = x_0 - t m, \qquad y = t n + y_0,
$$
for some $t$.

For which $c$ there is a $t$ such that 
$$x_0 - t m \ge 0, \qquad t n + y_0 \ge 0?\tag{eq}$$ 
We want
$$
\frac{x_0}{m} \ge t \ge \frac{y_0}{n}.
$$
There is definitely such a $t$ if 
$$
1 \le \frac{x_0}{m} - \frac{y_0}{n} = \frac{x_0 n - y_0 m}{mn} = \frac{z}{mn},
$$
or
$z \ge m n$.

To get the best-possible estimate $z \ge (n-1)(m-1)$, replace (eq) with 
$$
x_0 - t m > -1, \qquad t n + y_0 > -1\tag{eq'}
$$

Answer (score 2):

I can't talk of an incomplete proof, but I'd go as follows (hints):

$$\begin{align*}(1)&\;\;\min\{3a+5b\;;\;3a+5b> 0\;,\;(a,b)\in\Bbb N^2\}=8\\
(2)&\;\;\text{Induction on }\;\;n:\;\;n+1=3a+5b+1=\\
&\;\;=3a+5b+3\cdot 2+5\cdot(-1)=3\cdot(a+2)+5\cdot(b-1)\end{align*}$$

Now all is left is to show  $\,b-1\ge 0\;\ldots$and you may want to check some different cases.

Answer (score 1):

$3a=3\cdot a+0\cdot5$  which needs $a\ge0\implies 3a\ge 0$

$3a+1=3(a-3)+2\cdot5$  which needs $a\ge3\implies 3a+1\ge 10$ so disallows $1,4,7$

$3a+2=3(a-1)+5\cdot5$  which needs $a\ge1\implies 3a+2\ge 5$  so disallows $2$

---

Iterating with $5$

$5b=5\cdot b+0\cdot3$ which needs $b\ge0\implies 5b\ge 0$

$5b+1=5(b-1)+2\cdot3$ which needs $b\ge1\implies 5b+1\ge 6$

$5b+3=5\cdot b+1\cdot3$ which needs $b\ge0\implies 5b+3\ge 3$

$5b+2=5(b-2)+3\cdot4$ which needs $b\ge2\implies 5b+2\ge 12$

$5b+4=5(b-1)+3\cdot3$  which needs $b\ge1\implies 5b+4\ge 9$

So, the only numbers those are not representable are $1,2,4,7$

Answer (score 0):

Let $n=3a + 5b$. This leads to:

$$ n\equiv 3a + 5b \equiv 5b \pmod 3$$

Now we have three possibilities:

**Case 1:**

$$ n \equiv 0 \pmod 3 \implies 5b \equiv 0 \pmod 3$$
$$ 5b \equiv 15 \pmod 3$$
$$ b \equiv 3 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$$

This means that if $ n \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, we can fix $b=0$ and $a=\frac{n}{3}$, which is an integer, because of the congruence relation.

**Case 2:**

$$ n \equiv 1 \pmod 3 \implies 5b \equiv 1 \pmod 3$$
$$ 5b \equiv 10 \pmod 3$$
$$ b \equiv 2 \pmod 3$$

This means that if $ n \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, we can fix $b=2$ and $a=\frac{n-10}{3}$, which is an integer, because $n \equiv 10 \pmod 3$, also $n-10$ can't be negative number, because $n \geq 8$ and the next number of the form $3k+1$ is 10.

**Case 3:**

$$ n \equiv 2 \pmod 3 \implies 5b \equiv 2 \pmod 3$$
$$ 5b \equiv 5 \pmod 3$$
$$ b \equiv 1 \pmod 3$$

This means that if $ n \equiv 1 \pmod 3$, we can fix $b=1$ and $a=\frac{n-5}{3}$, which is an integer, because $n \equiv 5 \pmod 3$.

Because we exhausted all the cases, we proved that there is an non-negative integer solutions $(a,b)$, for every $n \geq 8$

Q.E.D.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. However, I am not asking for the proof which I already understand, but rather the idea or strategy behind it.