# Can a number N be expressed as sum of different primes. And if so, can we say goldbach conjecture is just a special case of it?

Tags: prime-numbers, goldbachs-conjecture

I was looking into Goldbach Conjecture proof.

Is it proved that we can express any integer as a sum of different primes.

And if yes, Goldbach conjecture says we can do that with even numbers and only two primes...

Isn't Goldbach just a special case of this?

And can we move beyond this and say we can express any number as the sum of Say P primes.

I mean every even number is made up of 2's....

That's prime. Just more than two.

Comment: cf. [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1181222/proof-that-every-number-%E2%89%A5-8-can-be-represented-by-a-sum-of-fives-and-threes); but what about $N=1$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382663/prove-that-every-integer-n-geq-7-can-be-expressed-as-a-sum-of-distinct-primes

Comment: What is your question? If it's "Isn't Goldbach just a special case of this?", the answer is something like "Yes, but that doesn't really tell us anything interesting.".

Comment: Yes-here's an example: 24=19+5=17+7

Comment: @Sam This has been completely solved in the mean time. So, we can say, that every positive integer greater than $1$ is the sum of at most $4$ (not necessarily distinct) primes.

Comment: Every positive integer greater than $1$ is the sum of twos and threes, this is however a quite boring statement. If you want, you con consider Goldbach's conjecture as a strengthening of this statement, in fact the strongest statement of this kind for even numbers.