# How to prove that any even number, divided by 2 a number of times, would eventually turn into an odd number or 1?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How do I prove that any even number, divided by 2 a number of times, would eventually go down to an odd number or 1?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answer

Comment: Strong induction, noting that $\frac{1}{2} n < n$

Comment: "An odd number or 1" is redundant. Since 1 _is_ an odd number, it suffices to say "An odd number"

Comment: An odd question...

Comment: Hope this helps https://math.stackexchange.com/a/25919/1277478

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n$ be an even number. By the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic, we have that
$$n = 2^{m}\cdot p_{1}^{m_{1}} \cdots p_{k}^{m_{k}},$$ for some prime numbers $p_{i}$, with $p_{i} \not = p_{j}$ for all $i \not = j$, and $2 \not = p_{j}$ for all $j$, and  $m, \, m_{j} \geq 0$. Therefore, $\frac{n}{2^{m}}$ is an odd number. In other words, if we divide $n$ by $2$ $m$ times turn into an odd number.

Comment: Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).
It's best for site health to delete this answer (which also minimizes community time wasted on dupe processing.) Using FTA is overkill here.